# Evalute $\int x\sqrt{1-x}\,dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How do we integrate the following without substitution!:

$$\int x\sqrt{1-x}\,dx$$

My try:

$$\int x\sqrt{1-x}\,dx=\int\dfrac{x(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx-\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=I_1-I_2$$

$$I_1=-\int\dfrac{1-x-1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=\\-\int\sqrt{1-x}\,dx-\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=\dfrac23(1-x)^\frac32-2(1-x)^\frac12+C_1$$

But I really don't see what to do with $I_2$, so maybe that's not the right approach.

Comment: Idea: write the initial integral as $\int (x-1+1)\sqrt{1-x} dx$. :) That worked.

Comment: Well, if the only goal is to avoid substitution, then you could simply "guess" that the answer is of the form $(Ax+B)(1-x)^{3/2}$ and solve for $A,B$.

Comment: math.se users being math.se users and downvoting for no reason. Nope, I won't close the question as it is well formulated and I've exactly pointed what the difficulty was.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int x\sqrt{1-x}dx\\
=\int(1+x-1)\sqrt{1-x}dx
\\=\int\sqrt{1-x}dx-\int(1-x)^{\frac32}dx\\
=-\frac23(1-x)^{\frac32}+\frac25(1-x)^{\frac52}+C $$
I took the idea of Math Student.

Comment: Well, that's my idea. :)

Comment: You are not fast enough.:)

Comment: What do you mean? :) It's me who posted the question, so I came up with it, tried it and then posted that it works.

Comment: Well done though!

Comment: Did you know when you were posting? You are a deceiver!! :)@MathStudent

Comment: Nope, I did not. I came up with it after posting the question